# React children's when using HOC to wrap parent

Tags: react-i18next, react-16

I am using React 16.8.6 and I have the following structure:

page.js

```
<ParentComponent id="testData">
    <ChildComponent value={data => data.text} />
</ParentComponent>
```

parentComponent.tsx

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent<IParentProps> {
    ...
    render() {
        const items = this.props.children;
        <MiddleComponent items={items} />
    }
}
```

ParentContainer.ts

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent';

export default withTranslation()(ParentComponent);
```

I need to know inside of `MiddleComponent` the element type (**not as a String but as a React element since I am going to create a new Element based on it**) of each child (so, in this case I should have `ChildComponent`), but when I inspect with chrome, all my children have a `I18nextWithTranslation` type...

Any idea how to fix this? Or if this is maybe a known bug?

If I don't use any hoc at all, when I write `child.type` it returns me `ChildComponent(props)`. But this is not true to when I am using hocs to wrap the parent...

Comment: What do you mean by you need to know the type of the element? Do you need to know what type of HTML element it is or?

Comment: Also, where at, within this component tree are you trying to gain the type of element?

Comment: Inside render(), I need to get which component is the child. So, if parent has 2 children ‘Child1’ ‘Child2’ I need the type of the component...

Comment: Could you assign a displayName on the component and check against it? See my answer below.

Comment: No, displayName would only give me a String, I need the component function that can be returned by child.type. child.type works the way I need IF there is no HOC element involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was very stupid...

I was importing the `<ChildComponent>` as a default import even though the child was not exported as default.

Basically

`import ChildComponent from ''` instead of `import { ChildComponent } from ''`

Answer (score -1):

In the example below, we're setting Component.displayName on our components so we can access that property in parents. This is a super trivial example that could be expanded to work with an array of children if needed.

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
    return <div>child render</div>
}

ChildComponent.displayName = "MyComponentName"

const ParentComponent = ({ children }) => {
    // This is the type of component.. should output "MyComponentName"
    const childType = children.type.displayName

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Render Children</h1>

            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    return (
        <ParentComponent>
            <ChildComponent />
        </ParentComponent>
    )
}
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I don’t need a String... so a displayName will not work. I need the function to generate the component. Again, the normal children > child.type behavior works just how I need.... but in my case the issue seems to be the withTranslation and/or any other HOC

Comment: On top of that, in order to access your displayName, I would need the exact same ‘type’ I am referring to . But again, this doesn’t work for me because of the withTranslation (or any other HOC)